# ReactJS + Ant Design: hook up two AntD components

Tags: reactjs, components, antd

I am a newbie and I have an issue that I need to connect two components(slider and radio buttons) from Ant design in React and make them collaborate together. So if I choose one of the options of the radio button, I want the slider to adjust the choice and conversely. For example, if I choose on the radio button year 2022 I want the to slider move to the right, and for example, if I choose 2022 on the slider I want to have checked radio button value 2022, and so on... I tried to put them into some conditions, but really don't know what to do with them. And also to have radio buttons in same width as slider.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Radio, Slider } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [currentValueRadio, setcurrentValueRadio] = React.useState(1);
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = React.useState();

  return (
    <>
      <Radio.Group
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log("radio checked", e.target.value);
          setcurrentValueRadio(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={currentValueRadio}
      >
        <Radio value={1}>2021</Radio>
        <Radio value={2}>2022</Radio>
      </Radio.Group>
      <Slider
        defaultValue={2021}
        min={2021}
        max={2022}
        style={{ width: 240 }}
        onChange={(value) => {
          console.log(currentValue);
          setCurrentValue(value);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/radio-group-antd-4-19-4-forked-134cps?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You have to use render() {} funtion to display your html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the state being controlled as a 'value' prop to both components, to have them syncronised.

```
<Slider
  value={currentValueRadio} // <- add a value prop
  defaultValue={2021}
  ...
```

Adding the value prop in your example will have both components react to the same state value.
However, since the Radio components set the value to 1 or 2, and the range on the Slider is from 2021 to 2022, you may not see the result you're looking for. Perhaps change the Radio values to 2021 and 2022 respectively.